# How does the equation (3.4.3 ) resulted after deforming C into C' ? Can anyone explain this?

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration, riemann-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

My question might be irrelevant or not according to the standard of this network. But I really appreciated if someone could explain the results in the image below. I really can't understand how the right hand side of the 3.4.3 is solved to a integral below in the image and pi is completely vanished. thanks
[see the details here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THmxs.png)

Comment: It is usually a good idea to include the image here (or even better, to write the text here, so that it stays here). Also, the text (in your image) refers to an image that is not visible. I think that you must fix those issues to have a surviving question.

Comment: @mickep roger that , has updated